# BLL returning the right Type of an instance

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, bll

I have a class "Artikel" and there i write some Business Logic. I also have a class "tArtikel" which is a type. In my class "Artikel" I work with "tArtikel" and returns are of that type. Now when i instantiate an "Artikel" i want it to be of type "tArtikel", so what i tried in my code is:

```
      public tArtikel Artikel()
      {
        tArtikel artikel = new tArtikel();
      }
```

Which results in: "'Artikel' member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type".

How would i set this up correctly?

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Are you trying to change the return type of the constructor? What would your constructor return? Is inheritance involved here or not?

Comment: No inheritance involved, i'm just trying to get my "Artikel" constructor to return a new instance of "tArtikel". I think that what i want is not even possible, so just forget this question :).
Sorry.

Comment: constructor does not have a return type - it always return the type of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class name is Artikel the only functions that can be named Artikel are constructors which in turn don't have a return type.

```
public Artikel()
{
}
```

Comment: I know, my question was probably just malformed and what I want is impossible and not properly figured out before asking.